# Java export only sepcific attributes to PDF

Tags: java

I have a class that contains a large amount of attributes:

```
public class Example {
 private String a, b, c, d, ...;
}
```

and  corresponding Filter object containing booleans:

```
public class ExampleFilter {
  private boolean a, b, c, d, ...;
}
```

Now I have a class where I write all the Strings of the example class into a pdf table and now I want to filter them.
I could use a if statement before writing each String property, but how could I do this better.
As I think that this is a common use case, could someone give me a hint?

Comment: This question is too broad, please complement it mentioning which tool are you using to generate the PDF and provide a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Since I am not looking for a concrete approach, I will not write an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other 2 options which you have are to use Reflection (which's not a good case).
Or, if you can, replace this 2 classes with using EnumMap<>
where key is name of the field (stored as enum) and the value - for one map - value, for other - boolean. And then merge them.